# Determining visible colors of defined cubes with face textures

Tags: math, graphics, 3d

I have an arbitrary number of cubes, each defined by pairs of (x,y,z) coordinates, representing opposite vertexes. (Specifically, they represent the vertex with minimal coordinates and maximal coordinates, respectively.) Each cube has a texture assigned to each face, from a simple 2D PNG file. (So for N cubes, there are 6N texture assignments.) These cubes are not rotated, so all faces are either parallel to or orthogonal to a single external "ground plane".

Wherever two faces overlap on the same plane, the last-defined cube's face is rendered. So for instance, if I define a red cube and then a blue cube, anywhere the two cubes have overlapping coplanar faces, it would appear blue, not red.

Assuming I can easily read the pixel values from the PNG texture files, how can I calculate the average visible color of the entire set of cubes from a given view angle? For simplicity, assume the viewing angles are all multiples of 90 degrees on any axis, so they're all pointing normal to a set of cube faces.

**EDIT** Oh, and one more possible kink: some textures have transparent pixels. Where this occurs, a face using these textures will be invisible and show through to any other cubes behind it. This must be accounted for in the color average as well.

Comment: 1. render image 2. compute its avg color. Where is the problem?

Comment: I should have been more clear: I need to compute this *without* actually rendering the cubes. Just from the cube/face definitions and 2D face texture files alone, without any 3D rendering at all, I need to compute the average color from a given viewing angle.

Comment: @IceMetaPunk rendering does not need to be shown on screen ... it can be done off screen. As you have textures than you must rasterize anyway. As you have just axis aligned cubes then it is really easy to implement even in low level simple DDA line rasterization will suffice. On top of that you just need to compute projection (I assume perspective) which will determine the range of your scene to be rasterized.

Comment: withou textures you could do this algebraically just from angle ranges of the cube vertexes but as you got texture that would do you no good as you would need to rasterize anyway (unless the texture is single color without any noise or data)